# angular karma jasmine unit test for a controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am adding a userController module to my SPA project with Jasmine on Karma.  I got an error saying "Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp.controllers due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp.controllers' is not available!". The app works fine. It just the unit test doesn't see the controller module for some reason.  Thanks for your help.

```js
/// <reference path="~/scripts/_references.js" />
/// <reference path="~/scripts/controllers/userController.js" />

'use strict';

describe('Controllers: userCtrl', function() {
      var scope, ctrl;

      beforeEach(function() {
        module('myApp.controllers');
      });

      beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('userCtrl', {
          $scope: scope
        });
      }));

      it("Should be false", function() {
        expect(false).toBeFalsy();
      });
    }
```

The mainController.js contains only two lines with ['myApp.factories'] as dependency in the module declaration like this:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myApp.factories']);
```

The actual controllers are in their own .js files, and have angular.module('myApp.controllers') without [ ] in the declaration. The userController.js is like this:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.controllers')
  .controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$window', 'version',
    function ($scope, $location, $window, version)
    {
      $scope.$root.title = 'AngularJS SPA | User';
      $scope.appVersion = version;
      $scope.title = 'User';
      $scope.content = "my contents goes here";
    }]);
```

In karma.conf.js, I have the following in the files: property.

```js
files: [
          'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
          'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
          'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
          'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
          'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
          'myApp/scripts/controllers/*.js',
          'myApp/scripts/tests/*.spec.js',
          'myApp/scripts/tests/**/*.spec.js'
        ],
```

Comment: Are you using require / browserify / webpack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from `myApp.factories`, I don't see this declared module anywhere in the karma files watcher. Before the controllers line, put the path of your `myApp.factories` module and should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

My Karma.conf.js now has the following but now Karma is complaining Error: [$injector:itkn] Incorrect injection token! Expected service name as string, got undefined.

```
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
  'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  'AngularSPA/Scripts/factories/services.js',
  'AngularSPA/Scripts/factories/factories.js',
  'AngularSPA/scripts/controllers/mainController.js',
  'AngularSPA/scripts/controllers/*.js',
  'AngularSPA/scripts/tests/*.spec.js',
  'AngularSPA/scripts/tests/**/*.js'
],
```

Comment: That could come from `version` that you try to inject in your controller. check if you give the declared file in your Karma conf.js. 
If `version` is the angular version that you use, you can simply reach it without any injection : `$scope.appVersion = angular.version( ) ` which return an object.

For more details : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/object/angular.version

Comment: Thank you.  the version is a value provider that I defined in service.js like this:
angular.module('cmtApp.services', [])
    .value('version', '5.0');