# Error: [$injector:itkn] Incorrect injection token! Expected service name as string, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

This a continuing of my question from [angualr karma jasmine unit test for a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194556/angualr-karma-jasmine-unit-test-for-a-controller).  I am getting

Error: [$injector:itkn] Incorrect injection token! Expected service name as string, got undefined. When I use [] in the controller constructor, I got

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- HomeCtrl

```js
 $controller("HomeCtrl",[{
              $scope: scope
            }]);
```

Thank you for your help.

```js
/// <reference path="../../_references.js" />

'use strict';

describe('Controllers: HomeCtrl', function() {
      var $controller, scope;
      beforeEach(module('myApp.controllers'));
      beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller("HomeCtrl", {
          $scope: scope
        });
      }));

      it('should has title equals to My App', function() {
        expect(scope.title).toEqual('My App');
      });
}
```

The HomeController.js is like this:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.controllers')
   // Path: /
  .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$window', /*'version'*/,
    function ($scope, $location, $window, version)
    {
      $scope.$root.title = 'AngularJS SPA | Home';
      //$scope.appVersion = version;
      $scope.title = 'My App';
    }]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$window', /*'version',*/
    function ($scope, $location, $window)
```

You have to remove the comma after the comment - like this you have 2 following commas which resolves to an undefined value. You also have to remove `version` from the function or the argument don't match with signature.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that I had an extra , in the controller. When I changed that, it worked.
, function($scope, $timeout ....